# What is wrong with my cyrillic text?

Tags: font-encodings, cyrillic

This is the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
This text is in Russian: проверка.
\end{document}
```

This is what TeXLive on Mac OS says:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live/MacPorts 2009_6)
entering extended mode
(./x.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty

! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `t2aenc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could install the [`cyrillic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cyrillic) package. This package contains the missing file `t2aenc.def` which is required for the T2A encoding.

On ubuntu, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-cyrillic
```

Comment: Thanks, I installed it with `sudo port install texlive-lang-cyrillic`

Comment: On Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-cyrillic`.